# Django registration form not hashing password

Tags: python, django

I'm building a student management system, but there's a problem. When I register a new user, i enter it's username, first name, last name, etc... and password of course. But when I save the form and insert the user in the database, the password is stored as plain text and not hashed. On the other hand, when I create user thru django admin panel the user password i hashed normally and login works...

Here is my code:

views.py

```
def addUser(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = AddNewUserForm()
    return render(request, 'addNewUser.html', {'form': form})
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddNewUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        form.password = password
        form.save(make_password(form.cleaned_data['password']))
        print("New user added!")
        return render(request, 'addNewUser.html', {'form': form})

return redirect('/users/')
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{form}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add new user">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is `AddNewUserForm`?

Comment: post your forms.py and models.py